# Execute selenium html tests from webdriver tests

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I use selenium, python webdriver to run my test application. I also have some selenium html tests that I would like to add to my application. This html tests are changing  quite ofen so I can not just convert those tests to python webdriver and add it to my app. I think I need somehow run those tests without changes from my python webdriver app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pySelenese module for python - it parses html test and let you run it.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a simple command line tool, using PhantomJS

You can check Simya from https://github.com/sonsuzdongu/simya

You can simple use simya as

```
phantomjs simya.js your-html-script output.py
```